# How was this image with red seats on a black and white background created?

Tags: post-processing, tone

What sort of post production process can help achieve this appearance?

http://500px.com/photo/5152024

Comment: Please read [this post on how to effectively ask "how to get this look" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I note that a wide angle lens was used and the vignetting seems overdone, so it could have a strong "postcrop vigneting" (LR calls it that). Secondly, curves have been adjusted for higher contrast and saturations other than red have been turned down, and red has been boosted I would guess (if it is a used subway cart the seats would be much more gloomy). People love local contrast enhancement these days, "clarity", so I bet he used that , too, to make details pop.

I tried these steps on the first random image I found on my HDD that had red in it. I call it a "BWR Image" (black white red image):

[image: BWR image]

*Note: I did it in imag view plus more, instead of lightroom, where I dont have saturation sliders per colour. Instead I turned it B&W and drew a "Blendback mask" on the red.*

Answer (score 1):

The main thing is it's a high contrast image, and then they've converted to B&W and used selective coloring for the red.

Similar image here [How can this lighting/color effect be done?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/how-can-this-lighting-color-effect-be-done/21847#21847) where selective coloring was used.

Comment: I think the fact that you find that other image to be very similar underscores my point about different people seeing different things in photographs!

Comment: selective coloring

Comment: It could also be about a very wide-angle lens. Not likely in this case really, however that's more of an effect to _my_ eye than any of the used coloring in that photo.

Comment: Yeah, I see the selective coloring, but... clean, cold, bright, sterile vs. gritty, warm, dramatic lighting, human model.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by shooting in raw, then splitting the image naturally in color channels.

I mean...you can do this...of course with mask and a color image with digitally splitted channels but in RAW or NEF is faster and more accurate.

By the looks of that image, i am most certain that the b&w is raw b&w or it used a camera with advanced configuration to store in-camera-b&w and color in the same time as only one dump from the sensor.