# How to do selective-color in Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, black-and-white, color-filters, selective-color

How to make the single color in a photography to be color and other parts changed to B&W?.

Don't know exactly the name of the effect, to be more clear in the following photo I want the green part to be green and other parts( leg and sandal) in B&W..

[image]

How to achieve that effect in Photoshop?

Comment: You already got an answer for Gimp and we already have an answer for Lightroom which may be interesting to you: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15315/how-can-i-create-a-grayscale-with-color-highlighting-effect-in-lightroom - So I made your question Photoshop specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the posts pointed to by @SteveKemp are good, there is a more general way to accomplish this in Photoshop. Basically, you do this:

- Duplicate the background layer
- Use your masking technique of choice to isolate the area that is to be turned black & white. In the case of the image below, Select > Color Range works nicely to select the blue jeans. After selecting the pants, I can go into QuickMask mode to tidy up the feet by painting on the mask. Many other selection options would work equally well.
- With the selection active, do Image > Adjust > Desaturate and only the stuff selected will be desaturated.

This effect is in a commercial post-production person's must-have bag o' tricks. It's useful in a number of situations and even if it's not to your taste or overused, it's really handy to understand how to do it. Beyond that, it's a short step from understanding how to do selective desaturation to gently dialing back saturation in image areas that are less important to draw attention. This may be a more artful technique.

Comment: +1 for posting a workable explanation rather than links that might die on the vine or be blocked by someone's home/corporate/national firewall

Answer (score 4):

This technique is called "selective desaturation", and you can do it using many techniques.

The following guide is for The Gimp, an opensource & free editor for Linux, Mac, and Windows machines:

- http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Selective_Color/

You added a "photoshopt" tag, so if you're using that editor in particular this guide might be more of a help to you:

- http://www.craigfergusonimages.com/2010/09/selective-desaturation-in-photoshop/

In general people do it to draw emphasis to a particular area of the photograph, by leaving it in colour.  I've always felt you draw eyes to particular areas of pictures by making them *interesting* above all, but some people like the look.

Comment: +1 for the 'interesting' point. Colour-popping is _so_ 2008.

Comment: Unfortunately the second URL is not working anymore, not sure if you can update it to e.g.: http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/selective-coloring/

Answer (score 2):

Use Black & White adjustment layer and by using the layer mask,you can define where it affects.

Comment: I think this is a better solution than desaturating as it gives you more control over the B&W portions of the image.